# android EditText Switches the keyboard on focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Android: I set editText Input Type as Number but when focus comes first time it opens alphanumeric keyboard then on second time it opens Numeric Keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Try to set xml in edittext input type like this way..

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    />
```